# How to display in a table this json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I need help to display this json in a table... the problem is that ng-repeat can't be used in this case.

```
    {
"dows": [
    {
        "dow": 1,
        "times": [
            {
                "open": "09:00:00",
                "close": "12:00:00",
            },
            {
                "open": "14:00:00",
                "close": "16:30:00",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "dow": 2,
        "times": [
            {
                "open": "09:00:00",
                "close": "12:30:00",
            },
            {
                "open": "14:00:00",
                "close": "19:45:00",
            }
        ]
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

every dow represent a `<td>` in html, and every elements of the times array, is a `<tr>` inside the the dow.

This is how I want it look 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zcado.jpg

Comment: Why can you not use `ng-repeat`?  Also what are you supposed to do with each item in the `times` array?

Comment: I add an image... I don't understand how i can use ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's too late to answer, but if you couldn't solve your problem yet,

then [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/gsjvq071/1/) can help you.

```
<tr ng-repeat="dow in dowArr track by dow.dow">
```

And if you want more information about ng-repeat,

refer below links.

**Official document of Angularjs - ngRepeat**

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

**Document of w3cschools.com - ngRepeat**

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-repeat.asp

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which Angular you are using, you could first push this data into an array in your component...

Only based on the snippet you supplied...

Something like:

```
var hello = []; //or hello: Array<any> = []; etc...
for(let h in dow.dows){
    hello.push(dow.dows[h])
}
```

Store the variable globally. This way, You can use

```
<div *ngFor="let dow of hello">
  <h2>{{dow.dow}}</h2>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let time of dow.times">
    <p>Time Open: {{time.open}}</p>
    <p>Time Close: {{time.close}}</p>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Again, I am only going based off the information supplied and not knowing which angular you are working with...

But hopefully this will help to some degree.

Comment: I add an image, is it like you supposed?

Comment: can you put it in a plunker?

Comment: Plunker was not cooperating when I ran it through. But I tried it out on my computer, and should work as stated.  However you are getting that response data, run it through a method like ngOnInit, or pass it through another -- where you will do as I mentioned, and store it into your global variable in the component -- so that the data is accessible in your html.  And use the layout provided (again, if this applies to the version you are using).

Sorry if this is not as helpful as you need.